# How to access http session object in jersey REST service?

Tags: rest, session

Hi i want to access data to anf from http session object in rest service i have googled a lot and find that @context of javax.ws.rs.core.Context gives HttpServlet object but as it is interfaec i always get it null. my code is as following

```
@Context
private HttpServletRequest request;
private HttpSession session = request.getSession(); 

@Path(value = "/listAllQuestion")
@GET
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public Response listAllQuestion(){
    int pgNo = 1;
    int pgSize = 5;
    IPResponse response = new IPResponse();
    try {
        if (session.getAttribute(IpConstants.TOPIC) != null
                && session.getAttribute(IpConstants.LEVEL) != null) {
                    session.removeAttribute(IpConstants.TOPIC);
                    session.removeAttribute(IpConstants.LEVEL); 
        }                                              
        session.setAttribute(IpConstants.PAGENO, pgNo);
        session.setAttribute(IpConstants.PAGESIZE, pgSize);
        quesList = questionService.listAllQuestion(pgNo, pgSize);
```

Comment: You should not use server side sessions by REST, because REST is about stateless communication, not stateful. Maybe it is intentional, that you cannot find a session object, I don't know.

Comment: Thanks for answering ..but i have checked it on many sites and i have seen using  @context annotation we can get HttpServletRequest request  object in rest but that too didnt work for me.

Comment: Did anybody find a solution..??
i have the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

please try this:

Move your request.getSession() down inside your listAllQuestion() method, as so:

```
public Response listAllQuestion(){
    HttpSession session = request.getSession():
```

I don't believe your request object will be populated outside the context of an actual request handler.